# Xcode project no longer showing symbols in call stack

Tags: xcode, macos, debug-symbols, macos-sierra

I have an Xcode project with a single Scheme that does nothing more than launch an OS X app in Debug configuration. The app is not built by the project, and the project does not have any targets. The Xcode project just launches the app from a Scheme. The app was originally built in Debug mode, via an external command-line build script, and contains a number of dynamic libraries (dylib's) in addition to the main executable.

After launching the app in this way through Xcode, if the app is stopped by an assertion statement (or is simply manually paused), the resulting call stack reveals nothing more than address pointers. There are no symbols displayed:

[image: Unsybolicated call stack]

However, if I force the assertion to continue, the app crashes and produces a fully-symbolicated crash report, despite an absence of dSYM files anywhere in the app distribution.

**[Edit]:** In addition, many of the symbols appear at the top of the Debugger Source Editor in many (but possibly not all) of the calls in the stack:

```
rendersystemtest`CMaterialSystem2AppSystemDict::SetupMaterialSystem:
    rendersystemtest[0x1cfb99] <+1753>: movb   $0x1, -0x51(%rbp)
    rendersystemtest[0x1cfb9d] <+1757>: movq   0x85c4e4(%rip), %rax      ; (void *)0x0000000000000000
    rendersystemtest[0x1cfba4] <+1764>: movb   -0x51(%rbp), %cl
    rendersystemtest[0x1cfba7] <+1767>: movq   (%rax), %rax
    rendersystemtest[0x1cfbaa] <+1770>: cmpq   -0x8(%rbp), %rax
    rendersystemtest[0x1cfbae] <+1774>: movb   %cl, -0x101(%rbp)
```

So, the symbols exist somewhere, they are just not being shown in the UI call stack.

Furthermore, this lack of call stack symbols is a recent result. Previously, the same executable displayed a symbolicated call stack when paused or stopped by an assertion:

[image]

My questions are:

1. What could have caused Xcode to stop showing symbols in the UI call stack?
2. If the symbols are available for a crash report, why can't Xcode display them in the UI call stack?
3. **[Edit]:** Why is Xcode displaying the symbol in the Debugger Source editor, but not in the call stack itself?

**[Edit 2016-11-05]** After further research, this seems to be environmental...and possibly related to an update to macOS Sierra. This problem does not occur on a similar MacBook running El Capitan.

Still have no idea what the root cause is though. Any input would be appreciated.